# Parentheses around assignment

Tags: javascript, frontend, variable-assignment, parentheses

I was trying to bind "window" to a function class for testing purposes and this appears

```js
function Dog() {} // OK, no problems here
function Dog() {}.bind(window) // Unexpected token .

(function Dog() {}).bind(window) // OK, no problems here

new Dog() // ReferenceError: Dog is not defined
```

Can anyone explain me why function class is not declared globally?
What parentheses do? It's in another scope?

Thank you

Comment: It's an expression then and not a function declaration statement.

Answer (score 1):

Binding to `window` doesn't change `window`. It doesn't even change `Dog`. `bind` just gives you back a function that works like `Dog`, but in which `this` is the same object as `window`. (Note that *it returns the bound function*. If you don't do something with the returned function, it will be discarded, and you won't see any effects at all.)

If you want to declare the function globally, you can say `window.Dog = function() { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

@chao thank you.

I was making a mistake

I was confusing class and function definitions.

In other words, if we create a new instance, the this would be linked to that instance. But if we call that function, instead of creating an instance, then it would modify window, because of the bind.